# user authentication for api without password (by using code sent trough sms)

Tags: authentication, ssl, hash

I have a mobile app that access my service. I don't require the user to create a password, but rather I send him a 4 character code that he uses to sign the data. Signing the data means applying a hash on on the message(sha258), using the code as hashKey. When the message reaches the server I apply the same hash on the message to see if the user is who pretends to be.

Should I just send the code with the message if I use SSL? Or is this practice ok?

Comment: What’s the point of hashing the code anyway?

Comment: I've edited as I missed that. I hash the message using the code as the key. Would you just send the code along with the message?

Comment: Hashing the code wouldn’t give much benefit. I mean, the hash could be easily reverted as hashing x^4 combinations is not much effort.